# Ошибка unable to resolve dependency tree при установке react-use-file

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm

я хочу установить библиотеку `react-use-file`, при помощи команды `npm install react-use-file`, но возникает ошибка:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: my-app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.13.1" from react-use-file@1.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-use-file
npm ERR!   react-use-file@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Danil\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-19T19_06_45_115Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Danil\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-19T19_06_45_115Z-debug-0.log
```

Как ее можно исправить?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю. `react-use-file` хочет 16 реакт. Вы можете конечно установить через `npm i react-use-file -f`, но это нужно проверять). Советую вам почитать объяснение в этом [ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66620869/15606261)